# Use of Laplace transform to solve a differential eqn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Use Laplace transform to solve:

$u_x = 2 u_t + u , u(x,0)=2e^{-3x}; $  $ u$ bounded for $x>0,t>0.$

$\frac{\bar{\partial{u}}}{\partial{x}}= 2 [s \bar{u}(x,s)-u(x,0)]+\bar{u}$

$\frac{\bar{\partial{u}}}{\partial{x}}=2[s\bar{u}-2e^{-3x}]+\bar{u}$

$\frac{\bar{\partial{u}}}{\partial{x}}=\bar{u}(2s+1)+2e^{-3x}$

$\bar{u}=\hat{u}x(2s+1)+\frac{2}{-3}e^{-3x}+B$

I dont know what comes next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$${{u}_{x}}=2{{u}_{t}}+u$$  $$u\left( x,0 \right)=2{{e}^{-3x}}$$ 
hence
$${{U}_{x}}=2\left( sU-u\left( 0,x \right) \right)+U$$
Where U is the laplace transform of u w.r.t t.  Therefore 
$${{U}_{x}}-\left( 2s+1 \right)U=-4{{e}^{-3x}}$$
Using an integrating factor one obtains
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}U{{e}^{-\left( 2s+1 \right)x}}=-4{{e}^{-3x}}{{e}^{-\left( 2s+1 \right)x}}$$
Solving yeilds
$$U=\frac{2}{\left( 2+s \right)}{{e}^{-3x}}+A\left( s \right){{e}^{\left( 2s+1 \right)x}}$$
Inverting we obtain 
$$u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{C}^{{}}{\frac{2{{e}^{-3x}}{{e}^{st}}}{\left( 2+s \right)}+A\left( s \right){{e}^{\left( 2s+1 \right)x}}{{e}^{st}}ds}$$
where the contour is the Bromwich contour.  Residue calculus yields
$$u\left( x,t \right)=2{{e}^{-3x-2t}}+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{C}^{{}}{A\left( s \right){{e}^{\left( 2s+1 \right)x}}{{e}^{st}}ds}$$
Note
$$u\left( x,0 \right)=2{{e}^{-3x}}+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{C}^{{}}{A\left( s \right){{e}^{\left( 2s+1 \right)x}}ds}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{C}^{{}}{A\left( s \right){{e}^{\left( 2s+1 \right)x}}ds}=0$$ 
And so A=0.  Therefore $$u\left( x,t \right)=2{{e}^{-3x-2t}}$$.